# Reordering members in a template by alignment

Tags: c++11, template-meta-programming

Assume I write the following code:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct dummy {
  T1 first;
  T2 second;
};
```

I would like to know in general how I can order members in a template class by descending size. In other words, I would like the above class to be

```
struct dummy {
  int first;
  char second;
};
```

when instantiated as `dummy<int, char>`. However, I would like to obtain

```
struct dummy {
  int second;
  char first;
};
```

in the case `dummy<char, int>`.

Comment: [Boost.MPL.sort](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/sort.html) ?

Comment: Considering, the order in which you declare your variables will be the order they appear instructs, you would need to create a constructor with the order you want l. Im assuming you would want dummy(char first_param, int second_para): first(first_param), second(second_param){}?

Answer (score 0):

On most platforms, padding for `std::pair` occurs only at "natural" alignment. This sort of padding will end up the same for either order.

For `std::tuple`, some arrangements can be more efficient than others, but the library can choose any memory layout it likes, so any TMP you add on top is only second-guessing.

In general, yes, you can define a sorting algorithm using templates, but it would be a fair bit of work.

Comment: I'm sorry that I used `pair` here as just an example, since it seemed to imply that I'm interested in the STL pair. I'm interested in a general technique for doing this. I also know that if I put these in an array, then you'll just get padding between the pairs, but it does make a small difference in an embedded environment with a small stack.

Comment: @JT1 Please show a realistic example where you expect an actual difference.

Comment: If you extend it to a triple instead of a pair, then `triple<char, short, char>` and `triple<char, char, short>` produces different sizes on the stack on gcc when I looked at the disassembly. Again, I put a pair there, since it would be the easiest example to work with if someone wants to show how it's done.

Comment: @JT1 Yes, but one would use `std::tuple`, not `triple`. Really, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to know how to in general reorder members in a template class by descending size to guarantee minimal memory footprint of a class instance. Again, I have no interest in the STL, so while I know a triple is called `std::tuple` and implemented as a variadic template, it has nothing to do with the question. In case you still ask, just take the whole question as an academic problem. The questions states precisely what I'm interested in. I'll remove the "why" completely, so no one will ask.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done, the only issue is the naming, how would you name your fields ??
I did what you are asking for not long time ago, I used `std::tuple`, and some meta-programming skills, I did a merge sort to reorder the template arguments, It is really fun to do (if you like functionnal programming).
For the naming I used some Macro to access the fields.

I really encourage you to do it by yourself, it is really interesting intellectually, however if you like to see some code, please tell me !